# Checking whether variable is between a couple of pairs of numbers? (Python 3.3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I suspect this question will have been asked before, so feel free to link, but I couldn't find it.

I want to write a program that will check if my variable a is between two certain numbers, otherwise check the next pair.
IE in psuedocode:

```
Check if variable is between 1000 and 2000
If it is, do this.
Else, check if variable is between 2000 and 3000
If it is, do this.
Else check if variable is between 3000 and 4000
If it is, do this.
```

I suspect it's easy, but I really can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use chained comparisons:

```
if 1000 <= foo < 2000:
   do_bar()
elif 2000 <= foo < 3000:
   do_quux()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
variable = 1500
if 1000 < variable < 2000:
    print ('1')
elif 2000 < variable < 3000:
    print ('2')
elif 3000 < variable < 4000:
    print ('3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second comparison all the time, since its implicitly satisfied because of the earlier comparisons:

```
if var < 1000:
    doLower1000()
elif var < 2000:
    doThis()
elif var < 3000:
    doThat()
elif var < 4000:
    doSomethingelse()
else:
    doSomethingBigger4000()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need a `list` to store the boundaries:

```
In [29]: rang = range(0, 5001, 1000)
    ...: foo = 1234
    ...: for i, v in enumerate(rang):
    ...:     if v <= foo < rang[i+1]:
    ...:         print (v, rang[i+1]), foo
    ...:         
(1000, 2000) 1234
```